# SQL query for a carriage return and Line Feed SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL query is only bringing back 1 Row #1

```
select  * from email_table  
where emailAddress like '%'+char(13)+'%'
```

[image]

Need to bring back first two rowsing with the carriage return in SQL 2008.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Are you certain there is a `Char(13)` in your actual table (I would agree it's there in your notepad++ view).

Comment: Yes i have done a cut n paste to check. I guess i can try an update with replace? These need to be removed

Comment: You don't have SET ROWCOUNT 1; in the SQL anywhere do you?

Comment: No just select *

Comment: I highly recommend that you search for `CHAR(10)` instead of `CHAR(13)` when looking for newlines. This handles the case where there are multiple different line ending characters embedded, since `CHAR(10)` is the *ix EOL character. Depending on your display method and copy method, the single `CHAR(10)` can be changed to `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` during the copy and paste process. Change your query to search by this, and see if you find both lines.

Comment: Tried with just Char(10) but this returns no rows

Comment: Can you give us the INSERT statements to create a table that will reproduce this issue?

Comment: Try this: SELECT *,REPLACE(REPLACE(EmailAddress,CHAR(13),'<<<CR>>>'),CHAR(10),'<<<LF>>>') from email_table;  Does the results on those rows show the replaced string?

Comment: No - Brings back the same result

Comment: If you don't see a  "<<<CR>>>" or "<<<LF>>>" in that new column, then the record doesn't have those characters in that field.

Comment: What is the output of this query: `SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(RTRIM(emailaddress), 1))` FROM ....`.

Comment: Output is 109  
109
109

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add a literal new line in your SQL:

```
select *
from @email_table
where emailAddress like '%
%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to troubleshoot:

```
/*DECLARE @email_table TABLE (emailaddress varchar(2000))
INSERT INTO @email_table(emailaddress) SELECT '#1gmail.com  ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
INSERT INTO @email_table(emailaddress) SELECT '#2gmail.com' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
INSERT INTO @email_table(emailaddress) SELECT '#3gmail.com'
*/

SELECT *,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),emailaddress) AS [Binary Representation]
FROM @email_table
--WHERE emailAddress LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'
```

The last characters of the [Binary Representation] row should be 0D0A (or 0D000A00 if the EmailAddress field is NVARCHAR), if they are not, [look up](https://www.asciitable.com/) what characters they actually are.

Comment: Email is varchar :  6D61696C2E636F6D20
6D61696C2E636F6D
6D61696C2E636F6D

Comment: @Rosebud That is not valid varbinary as there are spaces.